# how to handle paypal e-cheques

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am  unable to handle payments made through PayPal echeque on our application payment success page.

How do I handle PayPal echeque responses? We are using the code below  to handle responses.

```
try
    {
            LOgfile lg = new LOgfile();
            string strLive = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PaypalreturnURL"].ToString();
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strLive);

            //Set values for the request back
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
            string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
            strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";

            req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;


            StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            streamOut.Write(strRequest);
            streamOut.Close();
            StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
            streamIn.Close();
            NameValueCollection vale = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(strRequest);


            if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
            {
                trnsid = vale["txn_id"].ToString();
                string valecust = vale["custom"].ToString();
                string[] arycust = valecust.Split(',');

                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    if (arycust.Length > 0)
                    {
                       //Do something
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exd)
        {
            senderrormail(exd);
        }
```

Even if you can give the NVP response from paypal it would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different options that you have.

You can block eCheck Payments: 
[How to block payments in PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/setup-account/#id095FF4006HS)

You can setup Instant Payment Notifications and create a listener that will obtain the transaction details from PayPal. The details can include the payment_type of eCheck. Also you can be notified of transaction status changes from PayPal. The status change notifications will tell you when the eCheck clears and the funds are in your PayPal Account.

[Setting up Instant Payment Notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)
[IPN setup within PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/)
[How to create a Listener](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/)
[Payment Notification Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB04C0HS)
[IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSimulator/)
[Event Notifications with Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/#ide093f9b6-58c9-43be-b884-9f2de815c5b3)